# links with http://website in Dot net nuke 4.9 redirects to home page

Tags: asp.net, config, web

I have recently migrated from shared server to virtual dedicated server on godaddy.Every thing working  fine..but some link starts with http://sitename/..redirects to home page where as the link which opens with http://www.sitename/..works fine.I do have some changes in webconfig file.But i don't what is the reason?My portal running on DNN 4.9,IIS7,.net4.0 on virtual dedicated server.Previously on shared server it was on DNN 4.9,.net2.0 AND IIS 7.0.At that time every thing working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a description [here](http://www.petermoss.com/post/How-to-redirect-non-www-domain-to-www-domain-requests-in-IIS-7.aspx) of how to redirect foo/bar requests to www.foo/bar using the web.config file in IIS 7.

I suspect you have something like this in your web.config file but it is slightly wrong.